# My app add a character to the URL when calling Login

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working with an react app in front and every time i am calling login page its adding **#** in the url

**App.js**

```
...
import './App.scss'

const loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-3 text-center">Loading...</div>

const CVThequeIndex = React.lazy(() => import('./views/CVTheque/Index'))
const DepartIndex = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Depart/Index'))
const ServicesIndex = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Services/Index'))
const MonCvIndex = React.lazy(() => import('./views/MonCV/Index'))
const RecrutementIndex = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Recrutement/Index'))
const AccueilIndex = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Accueil/Index'))
const AdminIndex = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Admin/Index'))
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Login/Login'))
const PasswordRecover = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/PasswordRecover/PasswordRecover'))
const Error404 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Page404/Page404'))
const Error500 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Page500/Page500'))

...


return (
  <HashRouter>
    <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
      <Switch>
        <CollaborateurRoute path="/cvtheque" name="CVTheque" render={props => <CVThequeIndex {...props} />} />
        <CollaborateurRoute path="/depart" name="Depart" render={props => <DepartIndex {...props} />} />
        <CollaborateurRoute path="/services" name="Services" render={props => <ServicesIndex {...props} />} />
        <CollaborateurRoute path="/moncv" name="MonCv" render={props => <MonCvIndex {...props} />} />
        <CollaborateurRoute path="/recrutement" name="Recrutement" render={props => <RecrutementIndex {...props} />} />
        <CollaborateurRoute path="/accueil" name="Home" render={props => <AccueilIndex {...props} />} />
        <AdminRoute path="/admin" name="Admin" render={props => <AdminIndex {...props} />} />
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/deconnexion" name="Logout" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/connexion" name="Login" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
        <Route exact path="/" name="Login" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
        <Route exact path="" name="Login" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />

 ...
```

Every time i am trying to open Login page (or any other page) it is adding an # to the URL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using a `HashRouter`. I don't know for sure, but I'm assuming you're using React Router's `HashRouter`. You'll want to use the `BrowserRouter` if you don't want the hash symbol in the URL.
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: Yeah that's working with browserRouter but now the others URL doesn't work do i have to edit something else ?